# Scrollview cutting off the bottom of tiled-list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a scrollview in my React project that is supposed to list a map of data. these tiles also open accordion style in order to display more info. Nine items should be mapped and viewable, however scrollview only shows 7 and the last is cut off/the accordion and the tile itself.

Attempted: Creating a View around it with flex: 1, using FlexGrow instead of flex, adding height: 100.

```
<ScrollView style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.accordianContainer}>
          <Accordion
            sections={this.props.gyms}
            activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            renderContent={this._renderContent}
            onChange={this._updateSections}
            underlayColor={"#ffffff"}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
    contentContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
      accordianContainer: {
        height: ( Layout.noStatusBarHeight)* .9,
        width: Layout.window.width,
        marginBottom: Layout.window.height / 4,
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and I found a solution by adding an extra view with certain height on bottom of scrollview as :

```
<View style={{height: 54}} />
```

*Hope it helps you*.